# multiple activities in receiver

Tags: android

I want to run multiple activities in BroadcastReacevier. But its not working,
Only two activities are getting started.
SMSRxDialog getting called each time but SaveMessages and ShowMessages are not getting called. either one of them getting started at the same time. Which is secondly called.
If I start SaveMessage and then showMessage then sahow message is getting started but not starting save Message. or vice-Versa..
Is there need to stop first activity before starting another.

Thanks in Advance.

Following is the code:

```
package screenmagic.myfirstapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MQTTMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
{  
private static final String TAG = "MQTTMessageReceiver";
@Override   
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  
{  
    Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();  
    String newTopic = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_TOPIC);  
    String newData  = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_MSG);              
    Log.v("REG", "new Topic :" + newTopic);
    Log.v("REG", "new Data: "+ newData);


    Intent chatIntent = new Intent();
    chatIntent.setClass(context, SaveMessages.class);
    context.startActivity(chatIntent);  

    Intent di = new Intent();
    di.setClass(context, SMSRxDialog.class);
    di.putExtra(SMSRxDialog.SMS_FROM_ADDRESS_EXTRA, "MQTT");
    di.putExtra(SMSRxDialog.SMS_FROM_DISPLAY_NAME_EXTRA, newTopic);
    di.putExtra(SMSRxDialog.SMS_MESSAGE_EXTRA, newData);
    di.putExtra(SMSRxDialog.DIALOG_TITLE, "Chat Received");
    context.startActivity(di);  

    Intent msgIntent = new Intent();
    msgIntent.setClass(context, ShowMessages.class);
    context.startActivity(msgIntent);   

    }

}
```

I called three activities here, which are:

```
package screenmagic.myfirstapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ShowMessages extends Activity {
 DatabaseHandler db;
 private static final String TAG = "ShowMessages";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
   Log.i("REGISTER", " Calling showChatMessages");
   showChatMessages();

}

public void showChatMessages(){
      Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved:  showChatMessages" );
        Log.d(TAG, "Getting data from database ..");
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");

      List<Messages> message = db.getAllMessages();       

        for (Messages msg : message) {
            String log = "Id: "+msg.getID()+"Topic: "+msg.getTopic()+" ,From Host: " + msg.getFrom() + " ,Message: " + msg.getMessage();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Record: ", log);
        Log.d(TAG, "Data retrieved from database ..");
        }

}
}
```

another is :

```
package screenmagic.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SaveMessages extends Activity {
 DatabaseHandler db;
 private static final String TAG = "SaveMessages";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, " Creating  DatabaseHandler object");
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "Created  DatabaseHandler object");
    saveChatMessage();

}

public void saveChatMessage(){
      Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved:  saveChatMessage" );
      Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
      db.addMessage(new Messages(18,"txtbox.in123", "asmita","test MQTT message from Asmita"));
      Log.d("Insert: ", "Data inserted ..");

}
}
```

Third Acivity ::

```
package screenmagic.myfirstapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
//import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
//import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;


public class SMSRxDialog extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
 private static final String TAG = "SmsReceivedDialog";

    private static final int DIALOG_SHOW_MESSAGE = 1;

    public static final String SMS_FROM_ADDRESS_EXTRA = "com.example.android.apis.os.SMS_FROM_ADDRESS";
    public static final String SMS_FROM_DISPLAY_NAME_EXTRA = "com.example.android.apis.os.SMS_FROM_DISPLAY_NAME";
    public static final String SMS_MESSAGE_EXTRA = "com.example.android.apis.os.SMS_MESSAGE";
    public static final String DIALOG_TITLE = "screenmagic.myfirstapp.DIALOG_TITLE";

   // private TextToSpeech mTts;

    private String mFromDisplayName;
    private String mFromAddress;
    private String mMessage;
    private String mFullBodyString;
    private String mDialogTitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDialogTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString(DIALOG_TITLE);

        mFromAddress = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SMS_FROM_ADDRESS_EXTRA);
        mFromDisplayName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SMS_FROM_DISPLAY_NAME_EXTRA);
        mMessage = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SMS_MESSAGE_EXTRA);

         mFullBodyString = String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.sms_speak_string_format),
                mFromDisplayName,
                mMessage);

        extracted();
        //mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    }

    private void extracted() {
        showDialog(DIALOG_SHOW_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {
    /*if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "TTS language is not available.");
            } else {
                mTts.speak(mFullBodyString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }
        } else {
            // Initialization failed.
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not initialize TTS.");
        }

        */
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_SHOW_MESSAGE:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
                    .setTitle(mDialogTitle)
                    .setMessage(mFullBodyString)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.dismiss, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Database code is ::

```
package screenmagic.myfirstapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SMSMAGIC2";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "chatmessages";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FROM = "fromHost";
private static final String KEY_TOPIC = "topic";
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FROM + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TOPIC + " TEXT," +  KEY_MESSAGE + " TEXT )";
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Table create query:: "+CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Table created ..");

}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    Log.d("Upgrade: ", "Called onUpgrade function"+TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    Log.d("Insert: ", "Dropped Table created .."+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addMessage(Messages message) {

    Log.d("Insert: ", "addMessage function  ..");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message.getMessage()); // message 
    values.put(KEY_TOPIC, message.getTopic()); // topic Name
    values.put(KEY_FROM, message.getFrom()); // from
    values.put(KEY_ID, message.getID()); //Id 

    Log.d("Insert: ", "Message :"+ message.getMessage());
    Log.d("Insert: ", "topic :"+ message.getTopic());
    Log.d("Insert: ", "from :"+ message.getFrom());
    Log.d("Insert: ", "id :"+ message.getID());

    Log.d("Insert: ", "values added to ContentValues.");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i("Insert: ", "Object Created from SQLiteDatabase.");

    try {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserted Row..");
            db.close();
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Closing database connection.");
      } catch (Exception e) {
//           /   Toast.makeText(this, "misfunctioning open" + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Exception Row.."+e.getMessage());

        }

}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Messages> getAllMessages() {
    List<Messages> msgList = new ArrayList<Messages>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Log.d("Query :: ", "selectQuery ::"+selectQuery);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Messages message = new Messages();
            message.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            message.setTopic(cursor.getString(1));
            message.setFrom(cursor.getString(2));
            message.setMessage(cursor.getString(3));
            msgList.add(message);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return msgList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no point starting 3 activities from reciever as you dont know what the behaviour would be.

Always do A -> B -> C -> D  rather than directly A-> B,C,D

where A is your Reciever and B,C,D are your activities